# Static Inner class's non static fields real time utility and code syntax

Tags: java

What is the real time utility of non static fields inside static inner class? 
Also, how instance creation of static inner class works :

```
class Outer {
    static class Inner {
        public final String text = "Inner";
    }
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Outer.Inner().text);
    }
}
```

Comment: They're the member variables of the inner class. Their utility is the same as member variables of a top-level class.

Comment: `static` class means the class is not bound to an existing instance of the outer class, while `non static` classes are bound to an existing instance of the outer class. There is no logical connection to class members of the inner class.

Comment: real time = with a consistent latency, real world = non theoretical usage.

Comment: Peter, I didn't get your explanation of real time and real world. Could you please, elaborate it with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just consider static inner class as normal class (just placed inside class instead package) and consider non-static inner class something like generic, based on instance of outer class.